# How to fix local variable 'id' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I want to get a variable from a JSON file to python but it says that the local variable 'id' is referenced before assignment

```
def getInfo(name):
    with open("data.json") as file:
        file_data = json.load(file)

    for i in file_data["data"]:
        if i["name"] == name:
            id = i["id"]

    return id
```

Comment: It would be better to use another name, since `id` is a built-in function in Python.

Comment: I'm guessing you get to the return statement without meeting the condition to assign `id` ... just declare it ahead with a default value (or add an else statement), should resolve your error.

Comment: Think about what happens if `i["name"]` never matches `name`? In that case there is never an `id` variable defined (`id` is also the internal name of a function in Python, so usually you'd use `id_` instead). There is also no need for iterating further if you've found the element (unless you want the last one), so you could just `return i["id"]` instead. My last suggestion is to use a more descriptive name than `i` - i.e. what are these elements? users?

Comment: It would be nice to provide `data.json`.
You won't have an answer if we are reduced to guess the file format by reverse engineering your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

id is actully defined only in the for loop scope, so define it at the getInto scope so you could return it

```py
class Info:

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def getInfo(self,name):
        with open("data.json") as file:
            file_data = json.load(file)
        id=None # <<< here
        for i in file_data["data"]:
            if i["name"] == name:
                id = i["id"]


        return id
```

Comment: `for` loops do not have their own scope in Python.

Answer (score 1):

No need to specify a constructor if you don't do anything in it.

`getInfo()` stops iterating when it finds the `id`
No need to keep on looping once it has been found.

```py
class Info:
    def getInfo(self,name):
        with open("data.json") as file:
            file_data = json.load(file)
            for i in file_data["data"]:
                if i["name"] == name:
                    return i["id"]
        return None
```